# Running BASH Script on a Remote Windows Machine from Linux Machine

Tags: windows-7, linux, bash

I am planning to run a BASH script on a remote Windows system from my local Linux machine. For this purpose, I will have to login to Windows machine from the local one and then execute the BASH Script.

First of all, is this possible? If yes, then how can it be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to run a BASH script on windows
I do belive however that you could run a BATCH script remotely 
you could install http://www.freesshd.com/ on your windows machine
and run remote commands using putty's plink

Answer (score 0):

look into the [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tool from the SysInternals Suite to remotely execute a file on a Windows machine.

If you are actually talking about 'BaSH' / shell commands on windows then you need something like [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) which allows you to run sh commands on a windows machine, but has nothing to do with remotely executing.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Cygwin (Linux emulator) on Windows machine and than you will be able to execute your BASH script on Windows machine.